# Menu jitters on hover in IE7. HasLayout issue?

Tags: javascript, css, haslayout

When I test in IE7, the menu jitters on first mouseover and changes position slightly. Also, when hovering over a menu item that contains a submenu, the menu jitters again. I think both issues have to do with IE7 hasLayout but I'm not sure.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/VAuYx/)

Is there a way to ensure hasLayout in the css for IE7 on my menu  and sub-menu  tags? Or, are there text nodes being inserted somehow in IE7? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are right. Seems it was a [hasLayout issue with IE7](http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/gaps/white-space-bug.php).

I changed a CSS properties.

```
#nav {
    margin: 70px 0px 0px -15px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    display: inline-block; /* changed it to inline-block for IE compatibility */
    width: 195px; /* declared width since it's now inline-block */
    padding: 0 0 0 15px; /* total width 210px with padding */
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:20px; /* vertical center with line-height instead */
    color: #262626;
    height: 20px;
}

.subnav {
    margin: -26px 0 0 ;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left:196px;
    background: #201d1e;
    width: 325px;
}

/* same idea as (#nav li a) */
.subnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: 310px;
    line-height:20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The sub-menu renders a few pixels higher that the modern browsers, but the -26px on .subnav can be adjusted with a IE7 stylesheet. I think it's close to margin-top: -10px for IE7. Hope this works out.

http://jsfiddle.net/marioluevanos/VAuYx/11/

Comment: Thank you! I had updated `display: block` to `inline-block` before, but thought I was on the wrong track when the elements expanded to 100% width. Giving it a fixed width was the key.